# Why provide `until` and `unless` in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Is there any reason why Ruby provides `until` and `unless`? Is there any situation where `if` and `while` cannot do the job? What is the point of providing these alternatives?

Comment: "Is there any situation where if and while can not do the job?" No, you can always use negation. The only purpose is convenience and readability.

Comment: Actually, you don't need `if` either, `while` can do the job of `if` just fine. And you don't need `while` as well, polymorphic message dispatch and first-class procedures can do the job just fine.

Comment: You might as well ask why other languages *don't* provide them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any special reason why Ruby provide until and unless? Is there any situation where if and while can not do the job?

No. There is no technical reason to include this, or special cases that require it. You can accomplish the same thing with negation or other constructs.

> What is the point of providing those alternatives?

This is part of the central design philosophy of Ruby. Have a look at this quote from Ruby's creator, Yukihiro "Matz" Matsumoto, when asked about the guiding philosophy of the language:

> I believe people want to express themselves when they program. They don't want to fight with the language. Programming languages must feel natural to programmers. I tried to make people enjoy programming and concentrate on the fun and creative part of programming when they use Ruby.

http://www.linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/2001/11/29/ruby.html

Ruby is designed to make it as easy to express your thoughts in code as it is in English. Matz also focuses a lot on developer happiness that results from the freedom to be creative and expressive when writing code:

> For me the purpose of life is partly to have joy. Programmers often feel joy when they can concentrate on the creative side of programming, So Ruby is designed to make programmers happy.

http://www.artima.com/intv/rubyP.html

So, in short, these "superfluous" methods are there to add legibility, convenience and delight.